# Button onclick in layout programmatically injected into fragment causes error "Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity with a pageview. This pageview has three tabs and each tab has a fragment.
In one of the fragments I carry a RecyclerView. When the adapter Recyclerview return size = 0, I want to load a no_item_layout.xml. For this, I use this code in onCreateView of my fragment:

```
                  loadDataFromServer(new VolleyCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
                        mList = new ArrayList(list);

                        if (mList.size() > 0) {
                             ........

                        } else { 
                            LinearLayout linearContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_container);
                            View contentFragmentNoItens = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.no_item_layout, container, false);

                            btnShowAnotherTab = (Button) contentFragmentNoItens.findViewById(R.id.btn_show_another_tab);

                            txtSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            linearContainer.addView(contentFragmentNoItens); 

                            btnShowPesquisaTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                          Log.i(TAG,"clicked");
                                }
                            });


                        }

                    }
                });
```

The problem is that when I run the application, I get the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: android.thiago.com.br.picos, PID: 28031
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1596)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

This is no_item_layout.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    android:visibility="visible">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ANOTHER TAB"
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_another_tab"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: you are not using `no_item_layout` in your code but different one (which obviously contains another fragment)

Comment: Sorry. R.layout.content_fragment_list_no_itens and no_item_layout.xml is the same file. My mistake to write the question. I will edit